# VR Headset issue: objects displayed in one eye because of default shader. (in my case TextMeshPro shader)

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, virtual-reality

I have:

- Unity
- High Definition Render Pipeline (HDRP)
- Single pass rendering (no ability to change)
- VR Headset

Part of objects displayed only in one eye.

[image]

Investigation show that the reason of this -- **non-compatible shaders for such environment.** For particle system I have resolved such problem with own shader created  using ShaderGraph **(below is solution)**

But My problem of this question is:

***I have no idea how to write correct shader for TextMeshPro Text.***

Can anybody help with this?

---

THIS FIX WORKS FOR PARTICLE SYSTEM one eye issue: [Shadergraph shader](https://i.stack.imgur.com/piNtT.png)  (works well with transparency, Color over lifetime, etc)